# SQL Server Express installation required for clients connecting to a server?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005-express

I would like to know if an installation of SQL Server Express is required on my client PCs? I have searched a fair bit and so far all I've seen were related to attached databases or local databases.

Here's the setup of my system.

- There will be a Windows Server PC that will be hosting the SQL Server instance.
- Client PCs will be running a VBNet based windows form application where connection strings will be fed to table adapters that would allow them to connect to the server.

Now I have tested running the application on a Windows 7 PC without SQL Server Express installed and it works, connection was a success and data can be retrieved etc. However the system is actually going to be run on Windows XP when it goes live.

So I was wondering if the client PCs would require an installation of SQL Server Express or any sort of dlls for it to be able to connect to the server? Or would the .Net Framework be sufficient?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not require a SQL instance on your client PCs. The app can just make the connection to the server via the connection strings. Our app is very similar in the fact that we support Windows Xp and SQL Server 2005 and it works well without any instance on the client PCs. We do install a local instance on the client but this is only used when transferring data to a laptop so it can be used when disconnected from the network. HTH

Comment: Thanks for clarifying with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install .Net framework on your client pc. I'm not entirely sure if it's the case but to be sure, run it on a Windows XP machine. If you dont have an xp machine, try using desktop simulater like virtualbox of sorts.

Comment: .Net framework will certainly be installed as it's required to run my application. I was just wondering if the SQL queries would be able to run on an XP machine without having SQL installed on it. Or if VBNet would be able to handle that itself on deployment. Thanks for the suggestion on using virtualpc though.

Comment: I think the machine doesn't have to be installed with SQL.